# Store views / clicks in the flat file database on Bolt.cm website

Tags: content-management-system, bolt-cms

I have a site made with Bolt.cm. I would like to show the numbers of views for specific pages on my site on several places on a bolt.cm website.

How can I store these variables in the Bolt.cm flat-file database? How can I show the correct variables in the templates?

It would be nice if I could excludes some ip-addresses in the views. I am not a flat-file expert (yet) ;)

Example:

> Article 1 - How to dominate google - 5 views

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible by default, very deliberately.

You're far better off using something like Google Analytics for this sort of thing. Web servers get hammered by spiders/bot/crawlers and all sorts of things that would cripple your database performance in no time.  Not to mention the fun of trying to decide what is a *real* request.

You could then write an extension to query your Google account on each page load, though I really wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I would completely agree with @Gawain that it's much better to use Google Analytics, or maybe Piwik if you want control of your own data, should you wish to tackle it yourself then I'd suggest something along these lines, just before the `$app->run()` call.

```
$app->after(function($request){
    $data = json_encode(
        array(
            'route'=>$request->get("_route"), 
            'params'=>$request->get("_route_params"),
            'ip' => $request->server->get("REMOTE_ADDR")
        )
    );
    error_log($data, 3, '/path/to/logger.txt');
});
```

That would at least give you a fast write of the necessary data to a log file, which you could then use a job processing command to pick up and save to the db.

Whilst you could do all this in the after handler if you really wanted to, doing an extra db hit on every page load could unnecessarily slow down your app, so use caution.